# Symbolic Expectation Value Evaluation

Tags: evaluation, probability-or-statistics, symbolic, polynomials

Suppose an expression $Y=a +b X$, where $X$ is a random variable. I would like to find the 2nd order central moment of $Y$ in terms of the expectation value of $X$. For example,

$$E[Y] = a + b E[X]$$

and

$$E[Y^2] = a^2 + 2a b E[X] + b^2E[X^2]$$

which gives

$$Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2 = b^2E[X^2] - b^2E[X]^2$$

Can this be done using *Mathematica*? I am new to this environment, so please pardon me if I have not shown enough effort.

Arvind

Comment: Have a look at `Expectation`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks but this requires the distribution to be known, which is not the case in this problem

Comment: The distribution does not need to be known for the OP's purpose. As an aside (without answering the more general question the OP has asked), if $Y= a + b X$, then directly $Var(Y) = b^2 Var(X)$ (which is what you obtained the hard way).