# The definition of an Expectation operator

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In trying to answer to the question [Symbolic Expectation Value Evaluation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129423/symbolic-expectation-value-evaluation), I have written the following piece of code

```
 m /: m[x_] = If[Attributes[x] ==  Constant, x, m[x]];
 m /: m[x_ + y_] = m[x] + m[y];
 m /: m[x_  y_] = 
  Which[Attributes[x][[1]] == Constant, x  m[y],  
  Attributes[y][[1]] == Constant, y m[x], 
  Attributes[x][[1]] == Constant || Attributes[y][[1]] == Constant, 
  x y, Attributes[x][[1]] ! == Constant || 
  Attributes[y][[1]] ! == Constant, m[ x y]];
```

to begin with.

Then I have tried this

```
 SetAttributes[{α, β}, Constant] 
 m[α x + β]
```

which returns

```
 If[{} == Constant, x α, m[x α]] + If[{} == Constant, β, m[β]]
```

I do not know where is the problem perhaps the head of m[α x + β] which is Plus ????

Comment: Try `===`, does that work better?

Comment: Unfortunately not an  !=== seems not to be defined

Comment: You need  `=!=` then

Comment: Like this m /: m[x_] = If[Attributes[x] == Constant, x, m[x]];
m /: m[x_ + y_] = m[x] + m[y];
m /: m[x_ y_] = 
  Which[Attributes[x] == {Constant}, x m[y], 
   Attributes[y] === {Constant}, y m[x], 
   Attributes[x] =!= {Constant} || Attributes[y] =!= {Constant}, 
   x y, (Attributes[
       x] =!= {Constant}) || \[Not] (Attributes[y] =!= {Constant}), 
   m[x y]];
SetAttributes[{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, Constant]
m[\[Alpha] x + \[Beta]] it does not work neither

Comment: You still have `==` in the first def of `m[x_]`... The thing is, when you use `==`, stuff like `{} == Constant` is not `False`, it just does not evaluate, as you have seen from your output. With `===` it's either `True` or `False`.

Comment: Sorry Marius, it's holidays and I was obliged to come back home to feed my childs. Now m /: m[x_] = If[Attributes[x] === Constant, x, m[x]]; m /: 
 m[x_ + y_] = m[x] + m[y]; m /: m[x_ y_] = 
 Which[Attributes[x] === {Constant}, x m[y], make a long recursion.
  Attributes[y] === {Constant}, y m[x], 
  Attributes[x] =!= {Constant} || Attributes[y] =!= {Constant}, 
  x y, \[Not] (Attributes[x] =!= {Constant}) || \[Not] (Attributes[
       y] =!= {Constant}), 
  m[x y]]; SetAttributes[{\[Alpha], \[Beta]}, Constant] 
m[\[Alpha] x + \[Beta]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
ClearAll[m]
m[x_] := If[MemberQ[Attributes[x], Constant], x, Defer@m[x]]
m[x_ + y_] := m[x] + m[y]
m[x_ y_] := Which[
  MemberQ[Attributes[x], Constant], x m[y],
  MemberQ[Attributes[y], Constant], y m[x],
  MemberQ[Attributes[x], Constant] || MemberQ[Attributes[y], Constant], x y,
  FreeQ[Attributes[x], Constant] || FreeQ[Attributes[y], Constant], m[x y]
]
```

You then get:

```
SetAttributes[{a, b}, Constant]
m[a x + b]

(* Out: b + a m[x] *)
```